# Printing latex beamer slides (pdf) more than one per page

Tags: pdf, printing, formatting, latex

I have a PDF file that consists of slides in the Latex Beamer format. I only have the PDF, not the tex files.
I want to print these slides out and as there are about 1000 of them, I want to reformat the PDF so 2 or 4 slides are on one page. I can only print to A4 paper (and print to files). 
When I print into a file from my pdf viewer with the default options set to print 2 or 4 pages per sheet, I get a lot of white border area and the slides are unreadable, because they are too small. 
I want to remove the border area.

My favorised option is to do this back in Latex. I found [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4765/printing-beamer-slides), where the second answer is basically what I want, but I have not found a way to do this if I only have the PDF and not the individual slides.
If I just put

```
\includepdf{myFile.pdf}
```

where the slides are in the example, it does not work, but displays 4 white slides over the PDF file.
Alternatively, does anyone know a tool for printing with a user defined free scaling method for Ubuntu Linux?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: There is also `mpage` command (Linux), with many options.  I don't know how common it is across distributions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I found a solution that uses a tool outside of latex:

```
pdfnup --a4paper --keepinfo --nup 1x2 --frame true --scale 1 --no-landscape --outfile test.pdf myFile.pdf
```

This scales rather nice and prints 2 slides per A4 page.
Read [this](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/beamer-handout/) for more details.